# Parsing geojson with jquery and placing it on google maps?

Tags: jquery, json, google-maps, parsing

Everything seems to be working fine up to the point of actually placing the marker on the map. It pulls the json file from the server extracts the coordinates and applies them to myLatlng "All I really need from the json file....for now". All variable and coordinates can be viewed and logged in the console. But still no marker. I am familiar with map.data.loadGeoJson('/static/json/data.json') and that works fine however I plan on doing some more advanced stuff with the data and need to be able to make changes to each individual marker down the road so this will not suite my needs, as far as I know.

Heres my code

```
    function initialize() {
      var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
      var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(39.50, -98.35),
        zoom: 4,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions)


    $.getJSON("/static/json/data.json", function(data) {
        $.each(data.features, function(key, val){
           $.each(val.geometry, function(i, g){
                if (g ==="Point") {
                    x = 1;
                } else{
                    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(g[0], g[1]);
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: myLatlng,
                        map: map
                    });
                }
            })
        });

    });
  }
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

GEOJSON

```
    {
     "type": "FeatureCollection",
     "features": [
       {
         "type": "Feature",
         "properties": {},
         "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                -84.375,
                36.31512514748051
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
```

Comment: I'm sure the if (g==='Point'){ x=1;} looks weird. A label of "Point" was on the same level as the coordintates and was getting parsed into  myLatlng. That is just my way of dealing with the issue. Please let me know if there is a better one.

Comment: You could just use the addGeoJson method: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Data

Comment: Or https://github.com/JasonSanford/geojson-google-maps

Answer (score 0):

Mixed up my lat and long!. My markers were out of view. In Antarctica!

should be

```
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(g[1], g[0]);
```

instead of

```
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(g[0], g[1]);
```

with those changes this code works great!

Comment: You didn't provide any sample data, there was now way anyone besides you could have figured that out.

Comment: @geocodezip Thanks for the advice I added the JSON data for people who may run into similar issues